# How do you unlock costumes in Tokyo Jungle

Tags: tokyo-jungle

I know that Completing the "complete all (B, C, D etc.) Challenges" challenges unlocks different costumes
but those challenges arent showing up anymore?
Do you only get one chance to unlock costumes?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, these metachallenges are static, and will remain until you successfully complete them.

For example, the Wolf has four metachallenges for rank D through A (in addition to the three regular, random challenges in each rank) that each unlock a part of the "Guard Dog" set. On my first playthrough I completed metachallenge D and B, netting me two pieces of the set. The next time I started with the wolf, the metachallenges for rank A and C where still there, which allowed me to complete the set.

Once you've unlocked an item, you can usually purchase additional copies of it through the in-game store.